# Responsive JS page loading toward bottom instead of top

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design

I'm a new programmer working on my first RoR site (Rails 4.0.4, ruby 2.1.1p76). I've implemented a bootstrap theme (https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/journey-animated-landing-page-WB0K438LJ) with some responsive JS that allows text fading/background color changes based on scroll position.

Everything works well, except that when the page loads, it loads about 3/4 of the way down the page. I tried adding window.scrollTo(0,0); in my main.js file, which loads the page at the top, but then messes up all of the responsive features. When the page loads 3/4 down and I manually scroll to the top, the responsive feature work great.

I've spent several hours researching and haven't found a solution, so I don't think this is a repeat question, but I apologize if it is since JS is very new to me. Most of the issues point to Turbolinks, which I have already disabled.

Are there any alternatives to window.scrollTo(0,0); that might not mess with the function? Or a different workaround idea? Reason why it's not loading at the top to start?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT

main.js

```
$(function() {

  /*==========  Initalize steller for parrallax header  ==========*/

  $.stellar();

  /*==========  Initalize fit text for responsive text  ==========*/

  $(".fittext").fitText();

  /*==================================================================
  =            Hide elements if browser supports animation            =
  ==================================================================*/

  if(!Modernizr.cssanimations){
    //dont hide everything
  } else {
    $('.story-container, .story-image-container, .dot-container, .hr-container, .footer-container ').children().addClass('hide');
}

  /*-----  End of Hide elements if browser supports animation  ------*/

  /*=========================================================
  =            Use waypoint to trigger animation            =
  =========================================================*/

  $('.story-container, .story-image-container, .dot-container, .hr-container, .footer-container ').waypoint(function (direction) {

    if( direction == 'down'){

        if( $(this).children().data('delay') !== undefined ) {
            var delay = $(this).children().data('delay');
        } else {
            var delay = 0;
        }

        $(this).children().removeClass("hide").addClass("animated fadeInDown delay-" + delay );

    } else {

        $(this).children().addClass("hide").removeClass("animated fadeInDown");

    }

  }, { offset: '55%' });

  /*-----  End of Use waypoint to trigger animation  ------*/

  /*======================================================
  =            Waypoint for background colour            =
  ======================================================*/

   $('.color-change').waypoint(function (direction) {

    var colorUp = {
            backgroundColor: $(this).data('colorup')
        };            
    var colorDown = {
            backgroundColor: $(this).data('colordown')
        };

    if( direction == 'down'){

        $('body').animate( colorDown, 525 );

    } else {

        $('body').animate(colorUp, 525 );

    }

  }, { offset: '70%' });

  /*-----  End of Waypoint for background colour  ------*/

  /*===========================================
  =            Waypoint for header            =
  ===========================================*/

  $('#start').waypoint(function (direction) {

    if( direction == 'down'){

        $('#story-icons, #sub-title').fadeTo("300ms", 0);

    } else {

        $('#story-icons, #sub-title').fadeTo("300ms", 1);

    }

  }, { offset: '55%' });

  /*-----  End of Waypoint for header  ------*/

});
```

Comment: Could you please post your JavaScript code? Also, check to make sure your URL doesn't have an anchor tag in it that would cause the page to load at the specific anchor somewhere down the page. Like `www.example.com/responsive#anchor`. Lastly, and this is unrelated but pertinent to something you mentioned with Turbolinks. A gem called [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) will help fix most of your turbolinks issues with loading javascript.

Comment: @justin thanks for your response. I added the JS code in an edit. No anchor tag right now. Could I add one to the top? I was advised against that as it would cause a loop? Not sure if I understood that correctly.

Comment: You do not want to do that. I was just checking if that was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was a form at the bottom of the view with :autofocus => true that was pulling the page down.

http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-autofocus.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this bootstrap theme. But I'm willing to venture your offsets mean something. Try changing:

```
{ offset: '55%' }
```

To

```
{ offset: '0%' }
```

My hunch is this is what's causing problems.

Comment: thanks for your answer. :) Changing the offsets is affecting when the text fades and colors change, but didn't solve the loading error unfortunately. > the offset is causing the elements to appear sooner and < causes them to appear later.